# Pop-up message when site it accessed on mobile device

Tags: html, mobile, web, popupwindow

Is there a way to alert a user if he accesses my webpage on his mobile device ?

The reason for this is because this particular webpage is not coded in a way to be looked at on a mobile device (at least not yet)

So, if any would access the webpage on his mobile a pop-up will appear saying something like: "This webpage is currently not supported by mobile devices".

Would this be hard to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you need mobile detection script, have a look at following project on github. I have used it myself for similar requirements. This solution is for PHP (you haven't mention which technologies you been using).

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with Javascript as well, just google for Javascript Device Detection and you'll find enough. Another possibility is using CSS Media Queries; create a pop up, set it to display: none, and in your query make it visible again.